# call a class containing textView and a radio group in another class

Tags: java, android, code-snippets

Pleas i need your help. I created a class that i wish to to used accross multiple activity as shown below:

```
         public boolean valGndr(RadioGroup r, EditText s){
         RadioButton lastRBtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rd1);
         if(r.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1){   
         s.setText("please select your gender"); 
         s.setTextColor(Color.RED); 
         s.setTextSize(14);
        //  lastRBtn.setError("please select your gender");
        return  false;
    }else {   s.setText("Gender"); 
      s.setTextSize(20); return  true;}
}
```

So when I tried to call it in another activity, it gives error signs.The code i used to call the class is as shown below:

valGndr(g.getCheckedRadioButtonId(), sex.getText().toString().trim());

Please what am i doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: "So when I tried to call it in another activity, it gives error signs". What is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your class name but in you have to initialize the class in the activity before calling the valGndr() method

**do it this way :**

```
YourClassName obj=new YourClassName(); //Depending on your class name and type

//Then call your method this way
obj.valGndr(g,sex);
```

I hope it will work